# Random movement of objects to X,Y axes

Tags: python

I wrote the following Python, which is not ideal for me as it seems to be moving on the YZ axis

```
import bpy
import random

Num_Min = -0.01
Num_Max = 0.01

Target_Objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
for Target_Obj in Target_Objects:
 Target_Obj.location[1] = random.uniform(Num_Min, Num_Max)
 Target_Obj.location[2] = random.uniform(Num_Min, Num_Max)
```

I want to move to the XY axis.
Also, I want to control the range that can be moved by setting "Min & Max".

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean XY axis, But you might misunderstand the subscription for array in python. They should start at `0` not `1`. eg. `x = [3,6,9]; x[0] # is 3`. The `Object.location (Vector)` stand for `[X,Y,Z]` So you might need to use `location[0], location[1]` instead.

Instead of using number to retrieve axis, ones should use properties to get the axis for clearance. eg. `location.x = 1.0; location.y = 2.0`

```
import bpy
import random

constrain = (-0.01, 0.01) # I prefer to use tuple for min, max value

for target_obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: # PEP8 recommend to use lower snake case
  target_obj.location.x = random.uniform(*constrain) # And unpack them using *
  target_obj.location.y = random.uniform(*constrain)
  continue
  # Another approach
  target_obj.location.xy = (random.uniform(*constrain), random.uniform(*constrain))
  # There can be called and manipulated by combination as well
```

Comment: Sorry.
The z-axis means you want to fix it.
But this is what I think is the ideal behavior!
And it's a very straightforward code!
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry.
Just one more question.
What do I do if I want to specify separate numbers for the X and Y axes?

Example.

```
Xconstrain = (-10, -12)
Yconstrain = (-1, 2)

for target_obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
  target_obj.location.x = random.uniform(*constrain) 
  target_obj.location.y = random.uniform(*constrain)
```

Comment: then unpack them again using `*` sign: `target_obj.location.xy = (random.uniform(*Xconstrain), random.uniform(*Yconstrain))`. If you are not sure what code will do the effect you want, you can use the python interactive console inside Blender

Comment: I don't know how to merge those codes together...

Comment: Well, then you should learn how to use Python (Python 3) first. You can go find online jupyter notebook for learning as a Python playground. If you don't know how to use basic python, then you cannot literally do anything in Blender Scripting. Python should be easy to learn compare to Java or C# or even matlab in some degree.

Comment: That's for sure.
But in this case, it seems to have worked.
https://imgur.com/4BJKHs5
Thank you!!

Comment: The code after `continue` will not run, that's substitute of former 2 lines code. BTW that's a good habit to write down comment in the form you know, it will help you and other to know what you want to do in code.

Comment: https://imgur.com/undefined Now I can refer to the 3DCursor!
Very useful, thank you!